# Some titles too large in Chrome

Tags: bug, design, google-chrome

On Google Chrome 61.0.3163.98 under Android (that's the most recent version from Google Play), several tabs and some lists have a disproportionately large font. For example, the favorites tab in the profile shows as

[image: Google Chrome 61.0.3163.98]

whereas Chromium 37.0 and 62.0 (Linux) both show the titles in the expected size:

[image]

Some tabs have this problem, some do not have it:

```
activity_profile.answers          titles OK
activity_profile.questions        titles too large
activity_profile.favorites        titles too large
activity_profile.bounties.active  titles OK
activity_profile.bounties.offered titles too large
activity_profile.bounties.earned  titles too large
[tagname]                         sometimes titles too large, then also
                                  abstract too large
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289166/chrome-on-android-resizes-font

Comment: I've also had this happen in Review Queues in the past where the side items get way too large.