# Mostly no hovering of full site with mobile Firefox

Tags: bug, user-card

Using Firefox/57.0 on Android (most recent version from Google Play) with the full site, hovering almost never happens.

Hovering on a mobile device means:

1. touch the hoverable item - like a (shaded) gravatar or profile-picture,
2. wait until a menu pops up which suggests open in new tab &ct,
3. then touch back to remove the pop up, and then,
4. voilà – the hovering action goes off in no time...

Lengthy as this procedure seems to be it is still preferable to load the full profile page.

But this does not happen with FF.  However, it still shows the user card sometimes.

- Not always, when one clicks on the profile-picture to get to the profile and then says back - often then the profile-card pops up.
- Even stranger, when I somehow touch the profile-picture "correctly". Then the user-card pops up without any popup from step 2 above. I cannot really reproduce this directly. But it happens from time to time.

Other browsers like Chrome do hover on SO as expected but have their [own quirks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358612/772868).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the devs to do here. Sure, on many sites the workaround you describe works, but it's not an intentional feature.

Comment: @Stijn: Which workaround do you refer to?

Comment: The four steps you listed. That's a workaround to simulate hovering. It's not (afaik) an intentional feature provided by mobile browsers.

Comment: @Stijn: Used this since many years on Samsungs own browser and some more. Also note that there are **some** situations where FF seems to hover.

Comment: To elaborate, the mobile browsers handle events slightly differently from desktop. So it may not handle the "hovering" on mobile exactly the same way. See [this Android.SE for an example](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78626/how-to-trigger-mouse-over-in-android)

Comment: @Machavity: Thank you. The best answer in your link is exactly what I expect.

Comment: @false I still don't know what you want the SO devs to do about it, other than implementing touch events on the non-mobile site to provide proper support for mobile devices. There is no [meta-tag:bug] to fix here.

Comment: @Stijn: It is impossible for me to tell whose fault this is. It could be SO's or FF's. Therefore I report it.